# I can't load a 3D Model into my Playgrounds project in Xcode

Tags: scenekit, swift-playground, 3d-model

I'm doing a SceneKit project using Playgrounds in Xcode. However, when I try to load my field model into the scene, it never appears. I did some debugging and I think my function is not being able to find the file.

Here's my code:

```
    // MARK: - Field Setup
    private func setupField() {
        
        if let modelNode = loadField() {
            // Positioning and scaling
            modelNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -32.5)
            modelNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
            
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelNode)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func loadField() -> SCNNode? {
        
        // Tries to find a scene named "field.dae"
        if let fieldScene = SCNScene(named: "field.dae") {
            
            let modelNode = SCNNode()
            
            for childNode in fieldScene.rootNode.childNodes {
                modelNode.addChildNode(childNode)
            }
            
            return modelNode
            
        }
        
        return nil
        
    }
    
}
```

The `loadField()` method stops in the if let statement and returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to write the full path of the model in the `if let fieldScene = SCNScene(named: "Full/Path/field.dae"`, it didn't work.
Maybe something with the .dae extension?

Comment: is your file "field.dae" located somewhere inside the "art.scnassets" folder? - inf not, it should be there. and referenced like so: "art.scnassets/field.dae" - also: did you try to make a new Project? (not playground) and run it on a device ot the simulator?